# Resolve interactively requested view models from composition root?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I recently started a WPF project which follows the MVVM pattern, of course. I'm trying to resolve the object graph for the view models once and once only (in the composition root, that is in the Startup event handler of the application) in order not to have any other class to be dependent on my IoC container:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
       // Composition Root

       var container = new UnityContainer();

       container.RegisterType<IResidentListViewModel, ResidentListViewModel>();
       container.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();

       container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>();

       var mainWindow = new MainWindow(container.Resolve<IMainViewModel>());

       Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
       mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

ResidentListViewModel in turn depends on IDataService:

```
private readonly IDataService dataService;

public ResidentListViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
   if (dataService == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("dataService");

   this.dataService = dataService;
}
```

Which is not an issue, as the container will resolve that dependency alright.

However, ResidentListviewModel has a Residents property that hits IDataService:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<IResidentViewModel> residents = new ObservableCollection<IResidentViewModel>(); 

public ObservableCollection<IResidentViewModel> Residents
{
   get
   {
      if (this.residents == null)
         LoadResidents();

      return this.residents;
   }
}
```

The trouble starts, when data is being loaded:

```
private async Task LoadResidents()
{
   if (!IsLoading)
   {
      IsLoading = true;

      var models = await this.dataService
         .ListResidents();

      var viewModels = models
         .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
         .ThenBy(m => m.Vorname)
         .Select(m => new ResidentViewModel(m.Z_PF, string.Format("{0}, {1}", m.Name, m.Vorname)));

      residents.Clear();

      foreach (var viewModel in viewModels)
         residents.Add(viewModel);

      IsLoading = false;
   }
}
```

I know, I know, repeatedly adding to an ObservableCollection is a no-go, but please bear with me here. See that shiny 'new' keyword there? That's the true culprit. I have no idea how to get rid of it without resigning to a service locator ('instance factory'), which in turn is an anti-pattern according to my favorite DI book author, Mark Seemann (yes, I do have the book and would recommend it to any C# developer).

I could, of course, inject the list of VMs itself, but that would move retrieval of data to the composition root (sounds like a bad idea) and I can just as easily come up with a scenario where the user selects an entry and the code has to retrieve data depending on that selection, putting me back on square one.

So the question is: Is there a way to handle this issue with that same single call from composition root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. Not *instance factory* anti-pattern, but [*abstract factory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern:

```
var viewModels = models
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
    .ThenBy(m => m.Vorname)
    .Select(m => residentViewModelFactory.CreateInstance(m));
```

The `residentViewModelFactory` is of course dependency provided as interface via constructor injection, which makes everything fine and testable, and of course *setup-able* from composition root (you register factory as one of components).

Comment: Registering the factory with the container and constructor injection instead of a static (read: global) service locator works for me :)

Comment: +1, although AFAICT, `residentViewModelFactory` isn't a Factory Method, but rather an Abstract Factory.

Comment: @MarkSeemann: do you mean that the `ResidentViewModelFactory` (class) is an *abstract factory* while `CreateInstance` would be a *factory method* on said abstract factory?

Comment: @jimmy_keen Interesting indeed. What would the implementation of the `.CreateInstance()` method be as far as creating the object is concerned? Would it be using "new" or would it be using the container to get/create an instance?

Comment: @jimmy_keen If you look up the original description of *Factory Method* in [Design Patterns](http://amzn.to/XBYukB), you'll see that it's described exclusively in terms of the *Template Method* pattern. Both of these patterns rely on inheritance for implementation. If, instead, you supply some sort of factory interface via composition, it's a *Strategy*, and, in this case, more specifically an *Abstract Factory*. The `CreateInstance` method on an interface isn't a pattern - it's just a method; so you can't call such a method a *Factory Method* and expect people to understand what you mean.

Comment: @MarkSeemann: thanks, I'll give it a look. Have to admit the nomenclature between *factory-...* patterns is a bit confusing to me and I tend to use generic *factory* term for components responsible for objects creation.

Comment: @Jaans: in this case, I suppose factory would be *newing* instances. If instead it would have to use container to get instances, I don't see much point for such *factory* existence as all it would do was delegation to container.

Comment: @Jaans Like jimmy_keen said, the factory news objects up. The scope of the container is limited to `OnStartup` (i.e. the composition root) and only serves to create the object graph. When it goes of of scope, there's no way around newing objects up.

Comment: @Jaans Perhaps you'll find this useful: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory